# Как загрузить файл на обменник HTTPS через приложение C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, возможно ли создать `php` или `html` запрос через `winforms C#` таким образом, как будто открыли браузер, зашли на файлообменник (к примеру dropmefiles), курсором мыши нажали на выбор файла на закачку - и файл загрузился. Без необходимости открывать сайт в браузере (но если это усложнит задачу, то устроит и такой вариант).

Если рассуждать отдаленно, то должен быть механизм заменяющий нажатие на кнопку `Upload` или `Browse` для выбора нужного файла, через приложение на `C#`.

Приложение имеет возможность определять полный путь к файлу, это позволит использовать сразу нужный файл, а не выбирать его из списка:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    string filePath = args[1]; // Полный путь к файлу
    label2.Text = filePath;
}
```

Comment: Такое возможно, вот только непонятно какой вы ответ ожидаете

Comment: Ищу в какую сторону копать, нужны подсказки, ссылки, чтобы сформировать вопрос более точно, и если это возможно то уже радует

Comment: Классы для работы с http протоколом: HttpWebRequest/HttpClient. Вам нужно понимать в html/javascript, смотреть через отладчик в браузере, какой запрос отправляется на сервер, и эмулировать его через классы для работы с http.

Comment: Вообще, stackoverflow для конкретных вопросов, а не для вопросов в серии "помогите сформулировать вопрос" или "дайте материалы на ознакомление, я когда-нибудь сформулирую".

Answer (score 0):

Возможно стоит посмотреть в сторону Selenium, он для тестирования фронта в веб приложениях, но для ваших целей тоже подойдет